# How to print declared static varibales of the class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is the simple code to fetch instance variable list and its value.

Below code provides output of list instance variables and its value. I required help to find static variables list and its value.

```
 class Test:
    x = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.a =10

 t = Test()       
 print("Instance Variables:",t.__dict__)
```

Actual  Results:

```
 Instance Variables: {'a': 10}
```

Expected results:

```
 Instance Variables: {'a': 10}
 Static Variable: {'x':10}
```

Comment: The term 'static' has not got the same meaning in Python as it does in Java or C++. Python's class namespace is just another dictionary namespace just like instances can have a namespace. Functions and integers are just two types of Python objects, you can have any number of types of objects referenced in a class namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes have a lot of attributes automatically, but they tend to start with `__`. So to get the rest, you can use something like:

```
{k:v for k,v in Test.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__') }
```

Result:

```
{'x': 10}
```